# Open a connection to DB using EF to execute adhoc query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm an asp.net guy hard-core and EF + MVC = ME + WTF.

I have a task to open a connection to each of our production database servers. Run a simple query "Select top 1 * from t1 where f1 > 1".

I thought I could just use system.data.sqlclient build the conn string, open the conn and execute a query.

That doesn't seem to be working. Each connection takes forever.

How would I get an instance of our db object to do this with EF. I've seen tons of dbcontext examples but I don't even know how to get that and what it is.

I need to connect to 20 seperate DB1,TBL1,FLD1 and execute the query above. If they all succeed return an int 200 to an MVC view if even one fails just return a 503.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the question ? How are we supposed to answer it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a reference to the underlying `DbConnection` in your EF using `Database.Connection`.

For example:

```
var dbConn = context.Database.Connection;

var cmd = dbConn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 * from t1 WHERE f1 > 1";

var results = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

More on [Raw SQL Queries with Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[From Microsoft doc - Sending Raw Commands To The Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql#sending-raw-commands-to-the-database)

A- If you do not know the entity

```
 using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blogNames = context.Database.SqlQuery<string>(
                       "SELECT Name FROM dbo.Blogs").ToList();
}
```

B- If you know the entity

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blogs = context.Blogs.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.Blogs").ToList();
}
```